# Tcp xml communication C#

Tags: c#, xml, tcp

I need to set up a two-way communication over tcp using xml messages. What would be the best way to impelement this? I am not sure the messages will end with a `\n`. I have thought about using the `TcpClient.GetStream()`, reading the stream `byte` after `byte` and checking whether a complete xml message has arrived. But that sounds like it should be possible to do that better.

Important to know:

- It is a bare tcp communication, no http or whatsoever.
- One on one communication not like a web server connecting to many clients
- Like said before I can not be sure the other side will end the message with a `\n`

Comment: Do you implement both sides, or does the "other side" already exist? If you create both sides, you can _make_ sure it ends messages with an `\n` if that's what you want.

Comment: No I only implement one side, other side might be the same but might also be from another supplier

Comment: But are you the one who defines the format, or does the other supplier do this? You'll need to be very specific with the other supplier on what format is supported in your solutions. You can't work with "it might end with `\n`" - you'd end up scanning for a closing root element and a single corrupted xml message could essentially halt your communication indefinitely.

Comment: No, I have received a spec file. This does not say anything about the new line. So to be shure i conclude there is none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have received a spec that indicates that:

- xml is being sent over TCP, without a header or end-of-message indicator
- multiple messages are sent over the same connection

In this case, the only way to figure out where a (valid) xml message ends is to parse its structure and find the closing element of the root node. Treating the xml declaration `<?xml ...?>` as a message separator would not be reliable unless this is *guaranteed* to be included with each xml message.

If I were you I'd try to convince the other party that this is not a reliable message protocol - all it takes is one corrupt xml file (missing a closing element for instance) and your program won't be able to process any subsequent message on that connection.

Otherwise I'd use an `XmlReader` with a `ConformanceLevel.Fragment` to read to the next start element and use its `ReadSubtree()` functionality to get individual messages. This "subtree reader" can then be supplied to `XmlDocument.Load()` for further processing. `XmlReader` would break on xml declarations (`<?xml ...?>`) for all but the first message though, so you'd need a `TextReader` in between the `XmlReader` and the stream to strip those.

All of this just to "make it work", it's far from ideal. If they would simply add a fixed-length header or use a well known protocol you would have a more reliable solution with less code.